# Configure Gmail in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

Getting error message and Outlook prompting for password repeatedly.

Task 'syssoftacademy@gmail.com - Receiving' reported error (0x800CCC92) : 'Your e-mail server rejected your login. Verify your user name and password in your account properties. Under Tools, click E-mail accounts. The server responded: -ERR [AUTH] Web login required: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754'

....

Comment: Did you follow everything on the support google page first?

Comment: Yes... I follow the same thing and done

Comment: it could be possible that you have IMAP disabled in your Gmail settings. Go to gmail -> settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP -> Check if IMAP is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem after a long discussion:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b2dd08b0-05ac-47a7-83ed-c09f6ed6241b/unable-to-configure-gmail-in-outook-2007?forum=outlook

Actually, the problem is that I was trying to connect Gmail with Outlook again and again before turned on "allow less secure apps" resultant Gmail blocked from accessing the mail server.

Now, I have successfully configured my Gmail account in Microsoft Outlook.

Thanks for the community to spent their time on solving the problem.